# What is more predominant, PyObjC or PlistBuddy?

Tags: xcode, python, plist

I'm writing a script that will update an Xcode project's Info.plist. This script will be distributed to clients. In order to do this, I'd like to know what tools are more appropriate if I need to assume information about someone's system.

What I can assume:

- They are on a Mac that can build iOS apps for iOS 6+

I find myself at a fork in the road, I can write the script that calls a PyObc methods in order to update the plist file. Or I can use PlistBuddy to do the same thing. I'm wondering if anyone has any advice to which would be a safer assumption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy ships with OS X and doesn't need any developer tools or third party installation, you should assume that tool is ubiquitous and develop against that if at all possible.

I actually prefer `plutil` to convert things to XML or JSON and then use a script to make whatever changes are necessary, but your options are not bad ones to use either.

Comment: I decided to go with PlistBuddy. Thanks for the input. I was interested by plutil but I didn't seem to find a way to simple update a value. Thanks.

Comment: And eventually I switched over to plutil. Much more robust as I could convert into json and mess around with the structure, then convert back into a plist.

Comment: I find PlistBuddy can be handy for manipulating the values of keys that have dots in their names.